# HTML & Javascript - Using a loop to create buttons doesn't "individualize" .onclick = {}

Tags: javascript, html, loops, button, local-variables

I feel like this question has already been answered, but I couldn't find it, so I'll ask it anyways.

---

I was playing with Javascript in HTML, and I decided to make a whole bunch of buttons using a loop. I wanted to assign a function to each one based on which it was. Here, I'll show you the script:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = i;
    button.className = "buttonclass";
    button.onclick = function() {alert(i)};
    var buttonDiv = document.getElementById("buttons");
    buttonDiv.appendChild(button);
}
```

But when I click on any of the buttons, it returns a "6". I know where the problem is; I can't use simply `{alert(i)}`. But what should I use instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you are restricted to using [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) for browser support purposes, you can use functions to properly encapsulate some of these values so that the result isn't hoisted and set to the last value of `i`.

```js
function generateButtons() {
  var i;
  var buttonDiv = document.getElementById("buttons");
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      generateButton(i, buttonDiv);
  }
}

function generateButton(iteration, container) {
      var button = document.createElement("button");
      button.innerHTML = iteration;
      button.className = "buttonclass";
      button.onclick = function() { alert(iteration); }
      container.appendChild(button);
}

generateButtons();
```

```html
<div id="buttons"></div>
```

However, if you are able to use more modern containers like [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), then you can keep the simpler structure and leverage the magic of block scoped containers:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    let button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = i;
    button.className = "buttonclass";
    button.onclick = function() {alert(i)};
    let buttonDiv = document.getElementById("buttons");
    buttonDiv.appendChild(button);
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you call `alert(i)`, it is after the loop. After the loop, `i` is 6. You need to save the value of `i`, so you can call it later.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = i;
    button.className = "buttonclass";
    var buttonDiv = document.getElementById("buttons");
    buttonDiv.appendChild(button);
    let a = i
    button.onclick = function () { alert(a) };
}
```